# Random Numbers and arrays in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, random

I have an assignment in JavaScript to get a random number and display the random number which is no problem. How ever I have to attach an array to the random number to display the same number of items from the array that match that random number. My problem comes in with the odd numbers of the array items displaying correctly. For instance, if my random number is a 7, I will only get 6 items from the array. What can I do to fix this?

Here is my code:

```
var randomNum=Math.floor((Math.random()*9) + 6);

var amenities = ['Pool', 'Bowling Alley', 'Indoor Pool', 'Jacuzzi', 'Private Jacuzzi', 'Rooftop Hot tub', 'Indoor Putt Putt', 'Golf Driving Range',
'Live Music', 'Restaurant', 'Bar', 'Adult Entertainment', 'Free WiFi', 'Stocked Room Bar', 'Unlimited Room Calling']    

var list = document.getElementsByTagName('ul')[1];

for (var i = 1; i < randomNum ; i++){
var newItemLast = document.createElement('li');                    
var newTextLast = document.createTextNode(amentities[i]);                
newItemLast.appendChild(newTextLast);                              
list.appendChild(newItemLast);  



var newItemFirst = document.createElement('li');                   
var newTextFirst = document.createTextNode(amentities[i]);                
newItemFirst.appendChild(newTextFirst);                            
list.insertBefore(newItemFirst, list.firstChild);  
i++;
}

var listItems = document.querySelectorAll('li'); 


var heading = document.querySelector('h2');                        
var headingText = heading.firstChild.nodeValue;                    
//var totalItems = listItems.length;                                 
var newHeading =  headingText + '<span> ' + randomNum + '</span>'; 
heading.innerHTML = newHeading;
```

Comment: Impossible to say for sure since you haven't shown the offending code.

Comment: Also, you may want to clarify what you mean by "I have to attach an array to the random number".

Comment: most likely something wrong in the way you are iterating your array. A fiddle will be helpful

Comment: You only have a problem when the random number is odd, it works when it's even?

Comment: You can use `array.slice(0, random_number)` to get the first random_number elements in the array.

Comment: you will have to paste your buggy code to be able to make a sense of your problem

Answer (score 1):

As @Barmar says - you can use array.slice(0, random_number), but so that you can see whats going on, I did a sample as a straight javascript `for loop` that iterates over the array for as many items as the random number and  and appends a `<li>` into a display list.

Note that because the array is zero indexed the for loop will give as many array items as the random number that you have generated. This means that in your stated example of a 7 being therandom number - the following will give you 7 items - indexed at 0 - so it will be items 0,1,2,3,4,5,6 from the array - or in other words - 7 items starting at index 0 and ending at index 6.

Also - as a teaching moment - I am passing the random number to a second function that allows the display of the array items - this could totally be done in the same function - but just so that you get used to passing values to other functions - i thought it would be useful to see that this task is actually two (the generation of the random number and the slicing of the array into that subset).

```js
var array = ['item 1 ', 'item 2', 'item 3 ', 'item 4', 'item 5 ', 'item 6', 'item 7 ', 'item 8', 'item 9', 'item 10'];
  
function setNum() {
  var ranNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
  document.getElementById('displayNum').textContent="The random Number chosen = " + ranNum;
  setDisplay(ranNum)
}
 
function setDisplay(num) {
  document.getElementById('displayList').innerHTML = '';
  for(i = 0; i < num; i++){
    document.getElementById('displayList').innerHTML +='<li>' + array[i]+ '</li>';
    }
}
```

```html
<button type="button" onclick="setNum()">Click Me</button>
<hr/>
<p id ="displayNum"></p>
<ul id="displayList"></ul>
```